# Unhandled exception at 0x77662D37 (ntdll.dll) when reading png image with dimensions greater than 200x200 px

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unhandled-exception, libpng

I'm using libpng to read png files in Visual C++. The program works fine when reading image with dimensions 195x195px or less but crashes for higher dimensions.

This is the error message:

> First-chance exception at 0x77662D37 (ntdll.dll) in myprog.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xB4BFDDFF. Unhandled
>   exception at 0x77662D37 (ntdll.dll) in myprog.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0xB4BFDDFF.

and here this the code:

```
bool PngImage::load(void)
{
    png_structp pngPtr(NULL);
    png_infop infoPtr(NULL);
    FILE* fp(NULL);

    png_uint_32 w = 0, h = 0;
    int bit_depth, color_type, interlace_type;

    fp = fopen(fileName_.c_str(), "rb");
    if (!fp)
        return false;

    pngPtr = png_create_read_struct(PNG_LIBPNG_VER_STRING, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (!pngPtr)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        return false;
    }

    infoPtr = png_create_info_struct(pngPtr);
    if (!infoPtr)
    {
        fclose(fp);
        png_destroy_read_struct(&pngPtr, png_infopp_NULL, png_infopp_NULL);
        return false;
    }

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(pngPtr)))
    {
        png_destroy_read_struct(&pngPtr, &infoPtr, png_infopp_NULL);
        fclose(fp);
        return false;
    }

    png_init_io(pngPtr, fp);

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(pngPtr)))
    {
        png_destroy_read_struct(&pngPtr, &infoPtr, png_infopp_NULL);
        fclose(fp);
        return false;
    }

    png_read_info(pngPtr, infoPtr);

    png_get_IHDR(pngPtr, infoPtr, &w, &h,
        &bit_depth, &color_type, &interlace_type,
        int_p_NULL, int_p_NULL);

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(pngPtr)))
    {
        png_destroy_read_struct(&pngPtr, &infoPtr, png_infopp_NULL);
        fclose(fp);
        return false;
    }

    width_ = static_cast<size_t>(w);
    height_ = static_cast<size_t>(h);

    data_ = new png_bytep[height_];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < height_; ++i)
        data_[i] = new png_byte[width_ * BYTE_PER_PIXEL];

    png_read_image(pngPtr, data_);

    if (setjmp(png_jmpbuf(pngPtr)))
    {
        png_destroy_read_struct(&pngPtr, &infoPtr, png_infopp_NULL);
        fclose(fp);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < height_; ++i)
            delete[] data_[i];
        delete[] data_;
        data_ = NULL;
        width_ = height_ = 0;
        return false;
    }

    png_read_end(pngPtr, infoPtr);

    png_destroy_read_struct(&pngPtr, &infoPtr, png_infopp_NULL);

    fclose(fp);

    return true;
}
```

value of the constants:

```
const size_t BYTE_PER_PIXEL = 3;
const size_t RED_OFFSET = 0;
const size_t GREEN_OFFSET = 1;
const size_t BLUE_OFFSET = 2;
const png_byte BIT_DEPTH = 8;
```

The code seem to stop at png_destroy_read_struct(&pngPtr, &infoPtr, png_infopp_NULL); before fclose(fp).

What could be the reason why I am getting an Unhandled exception? Hope you can help with this. Thank you in advance.

PS: I am not that familiar with libpng

Comment: "I am not that familiar with libpng" - interesting form of self-punishment you have there. You may find [this article](http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html) an interesting read, as you seem to be missing a few things (like accounting for interlacing, validating the file signature, proper per-row sizing info, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothesis: This code assumes that every image is in 24-bit/pixel RGB format.

If you read a 32-bit/pixel RGBA image or a 48-bit/pixel RGB image, then the allocation

> data_[i] = new png_byte[width_ * BYTE_PER_PIXEL];

will not allocate enough bytes for each scan line.

C++ being the unsafe language that it is, the buffer overrun when reading into these too-short arrays will trash the heap data structures, which may not trigger a symptom until you try to free something.

Also, it looks like this code forgets to free the arrays in the successful case, or is `data_` an instance variable intended to hold the image in memory?

Comment: BTW, I recommend *always* using braces around `for` and `if` clauses. If you leave them out, it's too easy to get tripped up, e.g. by inserting a line of code to do debug logging.

Comment: Hi jerry! thank you for all your effort. You were right with your hypothesis. I found out that the image i'm reading is a 32-bit image and that causes the problem.

Comment: Glad to help. I don't understand the "put on hold as off-topic" since the question includes the desired behavior, the specific error, and relatively short code. The code given was sufficient to figure out the problem, and calling libpng doesn't get much simpler than this [although it needn't repeat `if (setjmp(...)) {...}` as much].